# how to correctly display the chart in adminhtml module

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, chart

I am trying to display a graph of employee statistics in the module

My function in controller

```
public function GraphicInfoAction()
    {
        $username = $this->getRequest()->getParam('username');
        if (!empty($username)) {
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->_title($this->__("Testing module statistic" . $username));
            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock("testing/adminhtml_testing_graphic"));

            $result = Mage::helper('testing/data')->getDataByLastDay($username);

            $this->renderLayout();
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('Please, select correctly user');
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
    }
```

In `block` i created Graphic.php file

```
class DaniilKrok_Testing_Block_Adminhtml_Testing_Graphic extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Abstract
{
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        var_dump('here');
        exit;
        //include 'Graphic.phtml';
    }
}
```

I don't really like connecting here `.phtml` file
If i include `.phtml` file in result i have this

[image]

Tell me how this logic can be implemented correctly?